# how to set captured image using android in sumsung device is portrait mode

Tags: android, android-camera, portrait

I'm trying below code to set captured image using android in sumsung device is portrait mode, but its set to landscape mode. Below code works fine for other devices excepts for samsung and sony.

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(yourimagepath);
String orientstring = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
int orientation = orientstring != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientstring) : ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
int rotateangle = 0;
if(orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) 
            rotateangle = 90;
if(orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) 
            rotateangle = 180;
if(orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) 
            rotateangle = 270;

mat.setRotate(rotateangle, (float) bmpPic.getWidth() / 2, (float) bmpPic.getHeight() / 2);

File f = new File(yourimagepath);       
Bitmap bmpPic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null); 
Bitmap bmpPic1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpPic, 0, 0, bmpPic.getWidth(), bmpPic.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

Is there is any other solution for same? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

use this in your manifest file in activity tag..

android:screenOrientation="portrait"

It can set portrait mode for all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Use ExifInterface to check the orientation of the image as stored in the device.

```
int rotate = 0;
try {
    File imageFile = new File(uploadFile.getPath());
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
            imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then using matrix rotate the bitmap to the actual portrait or landscape as stored in device.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

matrix.postRotate(rotate);

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
options.inDither = true;

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uploadFile.getPath(), options);

Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), true);

Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

rotatedBitmap is the bitmap with correct orientation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I was used it on different phones include samsung and it works perfectly:

```
public Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        //Rotate the image to get in correct position
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(mImagePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        }

        Bitmap rotatedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return rotatedImage;
    }
```

Hope it helps!